# RecyclerView não rola rápido

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Tenho um `RecyclerView` que só rola com o dedo colado na tela, se eu fazer aquele movimento rápido, para rolar bastante itens, ele so rola enquanto o dedo esta na tela, e depois para. Já refiz ele todo, e continua o problema.

XML:

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/recyclerViewOf"
    android:scrollbars="horizontal"
    android:clipToPadding="true"
    android:clipChildren="true" />
```

Java:

```
RecyclerView.LayoutManager lnm = new GridLayoutManager(getBaseContext(),2);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(lnm);
OfAdapter adapter = new OfAdapter(getBaseContext(),mList);
adapter.salvaContext(MainActivity.this);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Tenho outros `RecyclerView` no mesmo app que estão rolando normal.

Comment: Coloca o adapter.

Comment: ola, como assim?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e acrescente o código do OfAdapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma, estava usando collapsing e o meu `RecyclerView`, estava dentro de um `<include>`.

coloquei o `RecyclerView`dentro de um `Frame`:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical">...//resto do codigo
```

Colocando o `layout_height` com um tamanho padrão como no exemplo: 500dp, ele faz a rolagem como eu queria, quanto menor for o `layout_height` mais rápido fica a rolagem.

Se eu colocar `wrap` ou `match` funciona a rolagem, mas continua o problema como era inicialmente, não sei explicar o porque, mas assim está resolvido meu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Consegui amenizar este problema desta forma:

```
recycler_view.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
```